# How to add "active" css class to linkbutton code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have several linkbuttons in my master page. I need to add css class "Active" after I click each linkbutton and postback URLs.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="/News.aspx?lang=1"
         Text="News" OnClick="Linkbutton1_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Linkbutton 1

**Linkbutton 2** - class "active"

Linkbutton 3

I tried to add class using linkbutton onclick event, but after postback css class has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Put this to the `Linkbutton1_Click` method:

```
Linkbutton1.CssClass = "active";
```

[Article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx).

Comment: I already said than i tried to use onclick event but after postbacking url, css class had been removed.

Comment: So, is `News.aspx` the different page?

Comment: yes it is. I am using masterpage, to load other content pages, news aspx is content page

Comment: I suppose, which button is active actually depends on `?lang=1` URL parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

if you want write in code behind you can work with cookies:

**in Linkbutton1_Click method:**

```
Response.Cookies["Linkbutton1-cssClass"].Value = "active";
```

**in Page_Load method:**

```
if(Request.Cookies["Linkbutton1-cssClass"] != null)
   Linkbutton1.CssClass = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["Linkbutton1-cssClass"].Value);
```

finaly you can use `foreach` for all **LinkButtons**

Answer (score 0):

onclick of linkbutton call javascript function changestyle(SenderID)

```
<script type="javascript">
var strPreviousCahnge=""
function changestyle(SenderID)
{
   var LinkButtonActive=document.getelementbyid(senderID);
LinkButtonActive.className="subTabActive";

            if (strPreviousCahnge!= "" && strPreviousCahnge!= id)
            {
                var identity=document.getElementById(strPreviousCahnge);
                identity.className="subTabInactive";
            }
strPreviousCahnge=SenderID
}
</script>
```